# Powershell: Two questions about Get-AppxPackage and the -PackageTypeFilter parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am making a list of app packages installed on my system. In this specific case the ZuneMusic packages. I use the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -PackageTypeFilter Main, Bundle, Resource, Framework  | 
                 Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*ZuneMusic*"}
```

This will get me a list/result with 4 packages. I can see some have IsResourcePackage : True and one has IsBundle : True etc.
It seems this has to do with the -PackageTypeFilter cause if I only use Main is get only one result. I Looked up the parameter -PackageTypeFilter description:

***Specifies one or more comma-separated types of packages that the cmdlet gets from the package repository. Valid values are:
Bundle
Framework
Main
Resource
None***

1. Can someone elaborate/explain a bit more what this -PackageTypeFilter parameter does please?
2. If I want to delete packages of apps that I do not use or want. Do I use all options of this parameter and delete all the results or is one specific option enough?

Comment: if you do not use -PackageTypeFilter, only the main package will be displayed. If you remove the main package with `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*ZuneMusic*"} | Remove-AppxPackage`  , all others packages (Bundle, Resource, Framework) will be also removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you just do `get-appxpackage -name *zunemusic* -allusers | remove-appxpackage`?

1. dont use -packagetypefilter
2. the pipeline will get all the returned apps named `*zunemusic*` and remove them - however, if it floats your boat, specify each package individually

if you remove each package individually, possible future name changes could affect the script and will require manual update if so - probably unlikely though